# Symfony 5 : How to use 'data' in a entitytype field in a formtype file?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm creating a classic form where I have to add a name and select a value. I would like a value to be selected using the $id_combination_feature passed in the function. When I try this code in my controller, it works perfectly fine:

```
public function add_feature_value(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, CombinationFeatureRepository
    $combinationfeatureRepository, Request $request,  $id_combination_feature){

        $combinationFeature=$combinationfeatureRepository->find($id_combination_feature);
        $builder=$formFactory->createBuilder();
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,[
                'label'=>'Nom de la valeur',
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control mb-2',
                    'placeholder'=>'Nom de la valeur'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('feature', EntityType::class, [
                'label'=>'Valeur',
                'placeholder'=>'-- Choisissez une caractéristique--',
                'class'=>CombinationFeature::class,
                'choice_label'=>function(CombinationFeature $combinationFeature){
                    return ucfirst($combinationFeature->getName());
                },
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control'
                ],
                'data'=>$combinationFeature

            ])
        ;
        $form=$builder->getForm();
        $formView=$form->createView();

        return $this->render('admin/combination_feature/add_combination_feature_value.html.twig', [
            'request'=>$request,
            'formView'=>$formView,
        ]);
```

However, if I create a formType using `php bin/console make:form`, how can use the $id_combination_feature or the $combinationFeatureRepository ? I tried to autowire them and it didn't work:

```
class CombinationFeatureValueType extends AbstractType
{

    public $combinationFeatureRepository;
    public $id_combination_feature;

    public function __construct(CombinationFeatureRepository $combinationFeatureRepository, $id_combination_feature)
    {
        $this->combinationFeatureRepository=$combinationFeatureRepository;
        $this->id_combination_feature=$id_combination_feature;
        $this->combinationFeature=$combinationFeatureRepository->find($id_combination_feature);

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,[
                'label'=>'Nom de la valeur',
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control mb-2',
                    'placeholder'=>'Nom de la valeur'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('combinationFeature', EntityType::class, [
                'label'=>'Valeur',
                'placeholder'=>'-- Choisissez une caractéristique--',
                'class'=>CombinationFeature::class,
                'choice_label'=>function(CombinationFeature $combinationFeature){
                    return ucfirst($combinationFeature->getName());
                },
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control'
                ],
                'data'=>$this->combinationFeature
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CombinationFeatureValue::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass it through the form options.

In the controller where you are going to use the form you add what you want to pass inside the array of options.

```
$form = $this->createForm(CombinationFeatureValueType::class, $data, [
    'combinationFeatureRepository' => $combinationFeatureRepository, 
    'id_combination_feature' => $id_combination_feature
]);
```

And this way you can use it inside the formType.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $combinationFeatureRepository = $options['combinationFeatureRepository'];
    $id_combination_feature = $options['id_combination_feature'];
}
```

Wish could help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).